# Symfony 4 - Entity Listener "App\Entity\UserListener" declared on "App\Entity\User" not found

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I try to create an Entity Listener to trigger when i manipulate the User entity.

Here's my config so far :

**service.yaml :**

```
 user_listener:
      class: App\Doctrine\UserListener
      tags:
      - name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener
        entity: App\Entity\User
```

**UserListener.php** under src/Doctrine

```
<?php

namespace App\Doctrine;

class UserListener
{
    public function prePersist()
    {
        dump('test'); die;
    }
}
```

And my User entity class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"UserListener"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Il y à déjà un compte existant avec cet email.")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
```

I get this error :

```
Entity Listener "App\Entity\UserListener" declared on "App\Entity\User" not found.
```

But I never defined **App\Entity\UserListener** anywhere because **Userlistener** lives under the App\Doctrine namespace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you declare your userlistener like :
 @ORM\EntityListeners({"UserListener"})

Try adding the full namespace like
 @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\Doctrine\UserListener"})